# How to make the current click function work on iPad

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jquery-ui

The below code doesn't select field on ipad. How to make my click function work on iPad? Works fine on desktop just not iPad devices. All suggestions are welcome.

```js
var numbers = document.querySelectorAll(".attribute__swatch-link");
var letters = document.querySelectorAll(".border");

numbers.forEach(function(box, index) {

  box.addEventListener("click", function() {

    letters.forEach(function(box) {
      box.classList.remove("showBorder");
    });

    var info = document.getElementsByClassName('box-tip')[0];

    if (index > 2) {
      info.style.left = 11 + ((index - 3) * 47) + 'px';
    }
    else {
      info.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    }
    info.style.visibility = 'visible';

    letters[index].classList.add("showBorder");

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [Touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for JavaScript.

`"click"` does not work on multiple touch devices like the iPad.

For desktop and mobile support you can use:

`box.bind("click touchstart", function() {});`

Comment: will that cover desktop also? I need the function to fire on desktop and iPad.

Comment: touchstart, click breaks my code, doesn't fire at all, any idea?

Comment: for desktop and mobile you can use `box.bind("click touchstart", function() {})` - for more info you can use the [official W3 source](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/)

Comment: good answer but already tried and code breaks, any idea why? here's a fully working codepen http://codepen.io/gTwardochleb/pen/MmeQKX